# VCenter has failed, DHCP server is down

Tags: domain-controller, vmware-vcenter, dhcp-server

Our VCenter is crashing and technicians are trying to work on it, however this has resulted in the DHCP server failing, therefore none of the machines on the network can connect to the Domain controller or authenticate (except the people that were connected before hand and have not released their assigned IP address).

Does anyone have an idea on how to temporarily get people connected to the physical Domain controller (except the virtual DC, we also have physical one onsite)/allow them to authenticate?

Comment: So there are to domain controllers, physical and virtual; virtual has failed and you want refer users to physical DC?

Comment: Yes, and  DHCP is down any machine that released their ip address will not be able to get one. I know that we can manually give static IP address and point to IP addresses, however there is a 1000 people with machines in 4 different countries.

Comment: Add the DHCP role to the physical DC. Authorize the DHCP server. Create an appropriate scope with appropriate options. Profit.

Comment: Thats is fantastic, I will have to put the ranges manually correct?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a Scope appropriate for your network with the appropriate Scope options.

Comment: You are the best, please move your comments to the answer section and I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the DHCP role to the physical DC. Authorize the DHCP server. Create an appropriate scope with appropriate options.

You'll need to create a Scope appropriate for your network with the appropriate Scope options.